# Method store & posts not found [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, laravel

I've been stuck for a little while on a backend issue. PHPStorm tells me that the posts and store method doesn't exist, and I don't know which way to go to solve this problem...

File PostController.php:

```
public function store(){
     $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image']
        ]);

     $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');

     auth()->user()->posts()->create([
         'caption' => $data['caption'],
         'image' => $imagePath
         ]);

     return redirect()->route('profiles.show', ['user' => auth()->user()]);
    }
```

File User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

Error encountered:

[image: Top of error]

[image: Full error]

Comment: Can you show us your User model?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ of course, I just updated my post

Comment: Ok, you don't have defined a relationship between User and Post. You can define it similar to how you did it with Profile, but instead of hasOne, it would be a hasMany relationship. Your Post model has a user_id attribute, right?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thank you, I've answered my question just below, I've found the solution with your help and I thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't created a relationship posts in my User.php.

So I added the relationship this way:

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Post::create([
   'caption' => $data['caption'],
   'image' => $imagePath
]);
```